# How to nest tables without extending the inner table?

Tags: .net, itext

I am using itextsharp 5.5.3 in a .net project to generate a PDF file. I have a PdfPTable with two cells (in one row). I put another PdfPTable in each cell - first one with two rows and second one with three rows. The last row of the smaller table stretches to fill the space. How can I make the smaller table not to stretch and align to bottom of the cell it is placed in?

Comment: Show us your code: are you nesting the tables by using the constructor `new PdfPCell(table)` or are you adding the table using the `PdfPCell.AddElement()` method. It is custom to show some code when asking a question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the following screen shot:

[image: Screen shot]

This screen shot was taken from the result of the [`NestedTables`](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/NestedTables) example.

You are describing what happens when you add the table straight to another table (first table in the screen shot):

```
outerTable.addCell(innerTable);
```

Or maybe you are describing what happens when you add the table as a parameter for the constructor of a `PdfPCell` (second table in the screen shot):

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(innerTable);
outerTable.addCell(cell);
```

Note that the difference between both is subtle: when you add the inner table straight to the outer table, the padding of the default cell is taken into account. This padding is 2 by default. When you pass the inner table as a parameter to create a `PdfPCell`, the padding of the cell is 0 by default.

If I understand your question correctly, you want the behavior shown in the third table in the screen shot. That table shows what happens when you add the table to a `PdfPCell` first:

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.addElement(innerTable);
outerTable.addCell(cell);
```

You can align the inner table vertically like this:

```
cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM;
```

Comment: Using addElement method resolved the issue. Thank you very much for your help. Your book, documentation and stackoverflow answers helped me a lot while working with itextsharp. Thanks for all you do for the community.